# Drupal Views Content Profile User as an argument

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a normal Drupal User. I have used the content_profile module to create a profile content type. This content type contains a node reference to another content type company. The company node then references a type of node called Task.

I want to create a view that list all the tasks for a given user id.
So I imagine I would create a view with an argument of user id. Then I would add the relationship to the profile and the company and output the Task title.

The user id used seems to work on the created used ID and not the user id of the content profile that it is referencing. In our system the "admin" user creates the profiles so it causing some problems.

Any ideas? I feel I may need to write a custom module to do what I want.

Comment: Why not have the admin user assign the appropriate users to the content profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have answered a similar question in the past about how to create a view using part of the url as an argument to filter the view by the user profile. check out [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569867/drupal-views-display-recent-nodes-created-by-user-on-profile-page/2569951#2569951). the answer you are looking for may be a variation of my original response.

also, how are you creating those profiles? on one of my sites, when i created the profile page, its author ID is automatically changed to the user it is associated with.