# Drupal 7 - Display Recent Nodes on Profile Page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I haven't had much luck finding help for this in terms of Drupal 7, but this is the closest I've found:

[Drupal Views: Display recent nodes created by user on profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569867/drupal-views-display-recent-nodes-created-by-user-on-profile-page)

Basically, I want to access user pages at site.com/users/billy_joel, and have the users profile visible, plus a paginated list of their posts in reverse chronological order. I've tried messing around with Views, but I'm a little shaky with Drupal 7's Views.

Basically, I'd like the view to return an array of the posts so I can theme the results myself.

Has anyone done anything like this and does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use standard a view and theme the view results.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can create new views to list out the latest contents created by user and make user id as contextual filter which will get uid from url.

2.Create custome user profile page template with [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds)

3.Render view in user profile template.